# What are X_train and y_train?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I want to start develop an application using Machine Learning. I want to classify text - spam or not spam. I have 2 files - `spam.txt`, `ham.txt` - that contain thousand of sentences each file. If I want to use a classifier, let's say `LogisticRegression`.

For example, as I saw on the Internet, to fit my model I need to do like this:

```
`lr = LogisticRegression()
model = lr.fit(X_train, y_train)`
```

So here comes my question, what are actually `X_train` and `y_train`? How can I obtain them from my sentences? I searched on the Internet, I did not understand, here is my last call, I am pretty new to this topic. Thank you!

Comment: X_train is all the instance with attributes, y_train is the label of each instance. Because your problem is binary classification problem and using logistic regression. your y_train is either 0 or 1(spam or not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit)):

- `X` corresponds to your float feature matrix of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` (aka. the *design matrix* of your training set)
- `y` is the float target vector of shape `(n_samples,)` (the *label vector*). In your case, label `0` could correspond to a spam example, and `1` to a ham one

> The question is now about how to get a float feature matrix from text data.

A common scheme is to use a **tf-idf vectorisation** (more on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)), which is available in [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

The vectorisation can be chained with the logistic regression via the [`Pipeline`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) API of `sklearn`.

This is how the code would look like roughly

```
from itertools import chain

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

import numpy as np

# prepare string data
with open('spam.txt', 'r') as f:
   spam = f.readlines()

with open('ham.txt', 'r') as f:
   ham = f.readlines()

text_train = list(chain(spam, ham))

# prepare labels
labels_train = np.concatenate((np.zeros(len(spam)),np.ones(len(ham))))

# build pipeline
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
regressor = LogisticRegression()

pipeline = Pipeline([('vectorizer', vectorizer), ('regressor', regressor)])

# fit pipeline
pipeline.fit(text_train, labels_train)

# test predict
test = ["Is this spam or ham?"]
pipeline.predict(test) # value in [0,1]
```

Comment: Lets say I want to have 2 categories of text: test and train. I divide my data in 2 (80-20%, 70-30% whatever) and I can obtain `text_test` the same way as `text_train`? I am talking about obtaining `X_test` and `y_test`.

Comment: Yes you can. The pipeline will have learnt the _idf_ values of the vocabulary words present in your train set, as well as weight and bias in the logistic regression. `X_test` can thus be fed to the pipeline's `predict` method, which output can be compared to `y_test`.

Comment: syltruong I have some more questions, do you think you can help me via mail?

Comment: Holy cow! The explanation for the `X` and `Y` is hidden pretty well :-\